# How do you specify how much disk space for each mount point on vsphere?

Tags: vmware-esxi, vmware-vsphere, device-mapper

I created a vm via the vsphere web client. The ESX version is 6.5 and the vsphere version is also 6.5

Via the menu: create virtual machine
Option 2f: customize hardware
Virtual Hardware: New Hard disk

I selected 128GB and created my vm

But when I run `df -h` I see the following:

`Filesystem          Size  Mounted on
/dev/mapper/cl-root 50G   /
/dev/mapper/cl-home 75G   /home`

I would like to know what decided that the allocation would be 2:3 ?

**My question is:**
What would I need to have done to set more space to the root partition in the first place and less to the home partition? 
I don't remember seeing an option in the creation step.

I know these can be resized, but I'd rather avoid it in the first place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has nothing to do with the system being a VM. When you installed Linux I expect you told the installed to auto-partition the disk and the distribution's installed chose the 2:3 ratio. You would have needed to do a manual partition of the disk at the Linux install prompt to make your preferences known.

Answer (score 0):

If you choose Automatic partitioning in the RHEL/CentOS 7 installer, and more than 50 GiB of disk space is available after assigning swap space, then a logical volume of 50 GiB will be created for root, with the remaining space assigned to a /home logical volume. If these don't suit you, you can do the partitoning manually or make adjustments to the automatic configuration before committing to the installation.